# Magento 1.9.1 attribute list to display value when only one choice

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

For the attribute list it always displays "Choice an option".
If that is pertinent when there is several choices/values within the list it becomes not pertinent when the choice is only on value.

How to make Magento to directly display the value when there is only one within the list and to still display "Choice an option" when several values available.

Thanks in advance of your answer.

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution?

Comment: You can set default to any attribute option value. So that option value will be always selected even there one or more options."Choice an option" is a default value for select type attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition but the default would be at the attribute level and so defaulted on any product whatever the list has got only one or more values. As a exemple I have product 1 & 3 with 'color' attribute. For product 1 there are 5 colors options within the list and only 1 for product 3. What I want is to have the color value defaulted for product 3 but not for product 1. So I guess I have to use a programmatic solution that check how many values the attribute has got for a product and to defaulted only when there is only 1 value.

Comment: If someone knows where I can make that check - which file and part - I would be pleased cause I struggle to find by myself :-( Thanks